# SQL Select records with max date

Tags: mysql

I apologize for the formatting, I rarely write any code or use this site. I have a table that looks like this (with a few hundred `id_dealer`s and hundreds of thousands of `id_enrollment`s):

| id_dealer | created_at | id_enrollment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1200 | 2020-12-15 18:15:35 | 8287543 |
| 1201 | 2020-12-15 18:15:26 | 8287542 |

I'm trying to figure out which id_dealer's did not have an enrollment created today, so the max date for the `created_at` field < 2020-12-15, and I'm having trouble. Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A direct translation of your question uses `group by` and `having`:

```
select id_dealer
from mytable
group by id_dealer
having max(created_at) < current_date
```

Comment: Thank you! This is almost exactly what I need, just one criteria I forgot to mention.

I need the created_at field to show the most recent created_at date. Do you know how to add that criteria? When I run this I get what I'm looking for, it just doesn't have the most recent date in that created_at field.

Comment: @tuttle: just add `max(created_at)` to the `select` clause?